# Sending data to Two callbacks from one socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm making two Windows Forms application that can communicate with each other. I made them communicate them communicate with each other and made the data encryption and decryption between them . But now I need to make them exchange keys with Diffie-Hellman algorithm. I have a Asynchronous callback for the message exchange and one for key exchange  I want to know how to call the key exchange one when I need it because it always calls the message exchange one.
This is my code to connect with the other program locally:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPc1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPortc1.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);

            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPc2.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPortc2.Text));
            sck.Connect(epRemote);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            btnStart.Text = "Connected";
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnKey.Enabled = true;
            textMessage.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have two Asynchronous callback methods

> private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
>
> private void KeyCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)

This is how i send the data but it sends it to the MessageCallBack always how can i specify when to send to the MessageCallBack and when to KeyCallBack

```
         try
         {

            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtDiffieKey.Text) > 15 || Convert.ToInt32(txtDiffieKey.Text) <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number should be between 1-15");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

                MyDefaultKey = diffie_Hellman.DefaultMod(Convert.ToDouble(txtDiffieKey.Text)).ToString();

                var msg = enc.GetBytes(MyDefaultKey);

                sck.Send(msg);

                btnKey.Enabled = false;
                btnSend.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: This code is inherently broken because the `Receive` can receive any number of bytes and you appear to have no delimiters of any kind. It is not guaranteed to give you back what you sent; TCP/IP is stream-based, not message-based. Consider something like a line-based protocol and using a `StreamReader` wrapped around `NetworkStream`, or even WCF or gRPC; this is much simpler to deal with programmatically than raw socket operations. Using `async` / `await` with these approaches rather than `Begin...` / `End...` would eliminate the complications with callbacks.